# Disambiguation of [gp]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, blocklist-request

Tag info for [gp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gp)

> Microsoft Dynamics GP is a mid-market business accounting software or ERP Software package.

is very similar to that of [dynamics-gp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-gp)

> Microsoft Dynamics GP is one of several ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning, or accounting software) solutions offered by Microsoft under their Dynamics brand.

Additionally, while cleaning up questions tagged with it before this request I've encountered that were about:

- [pari-gp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pari-gp),
- [globalplatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/globalplatform),
- [gaussian-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaussian-process),
- [genetic-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic-programming),
- [greenplum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greenplum),
- gross profit.

I propose merging [gp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gp) into [dynamics-gp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-gp), and since this tag produces this much ambiguity (especially comparing to its rather small base of questions), I propose including it into stop list of tags after merging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed that a search for `[gp] -[microsoft-dynamics]` returns only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26717237), which mentions "Dynamic GP" (which sounds like it's supposed to refer to Dynamics GP).

[gp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gp) merged into [dynamics-gp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-gp), with no synonym created.  Blocklisting is declined for now, as this is the first time the tag has been removed, it was fairly low-volume even over many years, and it's not clear that it would be recreated (blocklisting is generally only done for tags that have been recreated after removal or are otherwise clearly going to be a problem).

```
updating post history, 17 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 15 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 9 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'gp': [gp] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 143
tag remapping of [dynamics-gp] and [gp] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
78 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```